# Rotating to point at something in radians without wrapping around zero

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

Let's say I have a circle with a line sticking out of it.

I want that line to point at the center of the window, no matter where the circle moves to.

***But,*** I want that line to *slowly move* to that angle. I don't want the rotation to be calculated and set every single frame, but rather calculated and *tweened* to that direction.

The issue I'm having with this is that if you move to make the line rotate around where the radians meet 0, it will do a full 360 (or 3.14 in rads ;) to get to that point.

I have spent a while trying to think of how to explain this best, [here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/quangogage/full/dKXGmX/) that can hopefully help clarify what I'm asking

```
// CenterX/Y is the center of the screen.
// dotX/Y is the center of the circle.
var angleToCenter=Math.atan2(centerY-dotY,centerX-dotX);

if (angleToCenter<currentAngle) {
  currentAngle-=0.05;    
} else {
  currentAngle+=0.05;
}
```

if you move to the right of the screen, then go above or below the center, you will see the line move in a full circle to try to get to the calculated direction. How do I avoid this? I want the line to seamlessly rotate to point at the center, via the shortest possible way, *not* by doing a full circle.

Comment: Great question.  Very different. I would have an inverse (-1) relationship defined for any location "below" the black circle.  Such that, if the red circle crosses a horizontal axis - whose boundry is defined by the black circle - the mathematical result to your equation is inversed.  This would make 0 degrees as we typically think of it, now positioned at 180 degrees.

Comment: @TobiahRex Perfect thank you! This worked excellently. If you leave this as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Awesome. Happy it worked for you @gage-hendy-ya-boy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. Very different.

I would have an inverse (-1) relationship defined for any location *below* the black circle. Such that, if the red circle crosses a horizontal axis - whose boundry is defined by the black circle - the mathematical result to your equation is inversed.

This would make 0 degrees as we typically think of it, now positioned at 180 degrees.

*Reasoning*: Looking at your CodePen it's obvious that the stem is going "the long way around", but you want it to go the "short way around".  The most intuitive way to make that happen would seem to be to inverse the red-circles calculated rotation. The simplest method I can think of would be to inverse the polarity of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the point where `angleToCenter` switches from `Math.PI` to `-Math.PI` (and vice versa).
Therefore I'd suggest you create an "epsilon angle distance", in which the angles will be hard-coded:

```js
var angleToCenter = Math.atan2(centerY - dotY, centerX - dotX);
var epsilon = 0.05;
if (Math.abs(angleToCenter - Math.PI) <= epsilon / 2 || Math.abs(angleToCenter + Math.PI) <= epsilon / 2) {
  if (dotY > centerY) {
    currentAngle = -Math.PI;
  } else if (dotY < centerY) {
    currentAngle = Math.PI;
  }
} else if (angleToCenter < currentAngle - epsilon) {
  currentAngle -= epsilon;
} else {
  currentAngle += epsilon;
}
```

For the full edit, you can check [my fork to your CodePan](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzrrQg)

Comment: Hmm I'm just not sure how effective this is. If you turn the Epsilon to a slower speed, say, 0.005 - You'll see it still circles all the way around to get to the calculated angle.

Comment: @GageHendyYaBoy you're right. You have to choose the epsilon depending on the speed of rotation. I've made a couple more changes in the CodePan and I believe it works much better now